# Edit the messaging menu at the top bar

Tags: 16.04, thunderbird, messaging-menu

Is it possible to change the position of the Thunderbird submenu to place it at the top of the messaging menu ?

[image: mail menu]

Thanks

Comment: Don't know, but you might want to ask on their forum http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewforum.php?f=39